# Comparing the size of the sets

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Let $A, B, C, D$ be sets. Prove that if $|A|=|B|$ and $|C|=|D|$, then $|A^C|=|B^D|$

I am asking for help in solving the task.

Comment: Do you mean $|A^C| = |B^D|$?

Comment: Yes, what I meant. But I don't know how to prove it.

Comment: Do you really mean the operation of raising a set to the power of set i.e. something like $A^C$?

Answer (score 0):

You have that $|A^C| = |A|^{|C|}$ and $|B^D| = |B|^{|D|}$ so, because $|A| = |B|$ and $|C| = |D|$, is trivial that $|A|^{|C|} = |B|^{|D|}$, meaning that $|A^C| = |B^D|$

Check: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cardinal_number#Cardinal_exponentiation

Comment: I'm understanding it. But I wonder that, is a correct proof?

Comment: Yes, why wouldn't it be? @Math

Comment: Have you already proved / learned in class that $|X^Y| = |X|^{|Y|}$? @Math

Comment: actually , no .

Comment: Are you familiar with cardinal arithmetic or carinal numbers? @Math

Comment: Let $\alpha$ and $\beta$ be two cardinal numbers such that $|A| = \alpha$ and $|B| = \beta$, then $\alpha^\beta$ is defined as |A^B| so this is a definition. @Math

Answer (score 0):

HINT: Since $|A|=|B|$, there is a bijection $f:A\to B$. Similarly, there is a bijection $g:C\to D$. Define a function $h:A^C\to B^D$ as follows: for each $\varphi\in A^C$ let

$$h(\varphi)=\{\langle g(c),f(a)\rangle:\varphi(c)=a\}\,.$$

Verify that $h(\varphi)$ is indeed a function from $D$ to $B$, and show that $h$ is a bijection. It may help to realize (or even prove) that $h(\varphi)=f\circ\varphi\circ g^{-1}$.

**Added:** Suppose that $\varphi,\psi\in A^C$, and $\varphi\ne\psi$; then there is a $c\in C$ such that $\varphi(c)\ne\psi(c)$. Let $a=\varphi(c)$; then $\langle g(c),f(a)\rangle\in h(\varphi)$, but $\langle g(c),f(a)\rangle\in h(\psi)$, since $\psi(c)\ne a$, so $h(\varphi)\ne h(\psi)$, and $h$ is injective.

Now let $\psi\in B^D$; we want to find a $\varphi\in A^C$ such that $h(\varphi)=\psi$. In other words, we want to find a $\varphi\in A^C$ such that

$$\psi=\{\langle g(c),f(a)\rangle:\varphi(c)=a\}\,.\tag{1}$$

Let $c\in C$; then $g(c)\in D$, and $\psi\big(g(c)\big)\in B$. The map $f$ is a bijection, so there is a unique $a\in A$ such that $f(a)=\psi\big(g(c)\big)$; let $\varphi(c)=a$. Then $\varphi(c)=a$ if and only if $f(a)=\psi\big(g(c)\big)$, which is true if and only if $\langle g(c),f(a)\rangle\in\psi$, so $(1)$ holds, i.e., $h(\varphi)=\psi. Thus, $h$ is also surjective and hence a bijection.

Comment: I don't quite know how to do it. Do you could help me?

Comment: @Math: Check the various requirements. Clearly $g(c)\in D$ and $f(a)\in B$ for every $\langle a,c\rangle\in\varphi$, so $h(\varphi)$ is a relation from $D$ to $C$. Let $x\in D$. The map $g$ is a bijection, so in particular it’s a surjection, and therefore there is a $c\in C$ such that $g(c)=d$. Thus, $\langle d,f(\varphi(c))\rangle\in h(\varphi)$, so the domain of $h(\varphi)$ is all of $D$. If $\langle d,b_1\rangle,\langle d,b_2\rangle\in h(\varphi)$, and $d=g(c)$, then $b_1=f(\varphi(c))=b_2$, so $h(\varphi)$ is a function. Thus, $h(\varphi)$ is a function from $D$ to $B$. You will need ...

Comment: ... to use similar techniques to show that $h$ is a bijection.

Comment: how to show that h is a bijection?

Comment: @Math: I’ve gone ahead and added that argument.